# Does data protection apply under a power of attorney relationship?

Tags: data-protection, email, power-of-attorney, austria, data

I have hired a relocation company to help me with dealing with the immigration office and I have signed a power of attorney so that they can visit the authorities and get feedback on my application on my behalf.

So far the relocation agency have been providing me with the names of the case workers and any relevant email exchanged with the immigration office but, recently, after the authority has illegally taken more time than they are allowed to so as to issue the residence permit (and I have mentioned to them that I am considering legal actions against the immigration office) the relocation agency refuse to provide me with any names or email communication due to data protection laws in Austria.

Does this make any sense? I mean, why am I paying them if they are allowed to hide information from me?

Comment: Questions for clarification: Who is the authority(I would assume the immigration office)? Who did you mention your consideration of legal action (and against whom), the immigration office or the relocation agency? And which of the two is refusing to provide you names or email communication?

Essentially I'm having an issue trying to parse your question.

Comment: @sharur : I have further clarified my question. I have a poa with the relocation agency and they refuse to provide me with the relevant emails they exchange with the immigration office about my application...

Comment: Names of case workers etc are not personal data in this context, so a refusal to provide you this information on data protection grounds seems far-fetched. Even if it were personal data, providing you this information would not be illegal since it clearly relates to you. Have you tried talking to the immigration office directly?

Comment: @amon: Thanks for the feedback. Finally, they did provide the needed info since the application started moving... My best guess is that, after seeing that I was ready to proceed legally, they were trying to protect their relationship with the immigration office (forgetting that I am their client) and they were making up some data protection rules..